# Office копипастит через раз

Tags: windows, office

Когда я пытаюсь выполнить копирование чего-либо из офисного приложения куда-либо, то копирование может не происходит с первого раза, т.е ничего не вставляется.

Раза с 5 после нажатия CTRL+C/CTRL+V что-то только копируется.

Если в Access делать копирование полей в дизайнере, то вылетает ошибка в таких случаях, что буфер недоступен.

Office 2016.

Чем это можно вылечить?

Comment: Проблемы с клавиатурой? Операции через контекстное меню нормально проходят?

Comment: @Anamnian, только в офисе такая хрень. Если бы так было везде, то я бы давно бы бомбанул.